# OSGi 4.3.0 in JBOSS AS 7.1.1

Tags: java, osgi, jboss7.x

Does JBOSS AS 7.1.1 support OSGi 4.3.1? Which is the latest version of Jbosi that can be used with JBOSS AS 7.1.1? 

I tried deploying OSGi 4.3.1 in to deployments.

I tried changing the version of 'compendium' from 4.2.0 to 4.3.1 in standalone.xml as shown below

```
            <capability name="org.asgi:org.osgi.compendium:4.3.1" startlevel="1"/>
```

Also I changed the version of Osgi used in my application to 4.3.1 in my pom.xml. 
I end up getting the below exception when I start the server.

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011900: Cannot start bundle: javax.persistence:2.1.0.v201304241213: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: org.eclipse.persistence.javax.persistence.osgi.Activator is not an implementation of org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator
    at org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.HostBundleState.transitionToActive(HostBundleState.java:302) [jbosgi-framework-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.HostBundleState.startInternal(HostBundleState.java:223) [jbosgi-framework-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.AbstractBundleState.start(AbstractBundleState.java:494) [jbosgi-framework-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.osgi.deployment.BundleStartTracker$1.processService(BundleStartTracker.java:144) [jboss-as-osgi-service-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.osgi.deployment.BundleStartTracker$1.transition(BundleStartTracker.java:119) [jboss-as-osgi-service-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.invokeListener(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1416) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.access$2700(ServiceControllerImpl.java:49) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ListenerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1954) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what OSGi specs versions Jboss supports excactly but you should never deploy the spec jars in OSGi. The OSGi core specs will be provided by the OSGi framework. 
For other specs like compendium or enterprise you should only deploy or embed the spec packages you need. Never deploy these jars as bundles.
The reason is that you eventually end up with two versions of the same spec which can lead consumers and providers of such services to bind to different spec packages. This then causes the consumers to not find the services.